# Why is there a gap between my select and options tags in blazor?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I am getting a gap between my select tag and its options and I want to get rid of it. I want the options to start right when the select ends.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-box">
        <label for="@Name">@Keyword.DisplayText.ToUpper()</label>
    </div>

    <ToolTip Name="@Name" KeywordType="combo" Text="@ToolTip">
        
            // Select is used when user must select an option
            <select class="@SelectClassName()" id="@Name" name="@Name" @bind="Value" required>
                @foreach (StandardChecklistOption comboOption in Keyword.Options.Values)
                {
                    @if (comboOption.Name != Keyword.DisplayText && comboOption.IsVisible(ProductLineId))
                    {
                        <option class="@Name" id="@comboOption.Name" Value="@comboOption.Name"> @comboOption.DisplayText</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
    </ToolTip>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
label {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: small;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
}
.outer-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
}
.inner-box {
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    border-bottom: medium solid #FFC72C;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    width: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 12px 0 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    align-content: center;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
select {
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 8px;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    height: fit-content;
    max-height: 38px;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 8px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]
[image]

I've tried to set a negative margin or padding for the options tag but it doesn't change anything.
I've also tried to delete all margins and paddings from all its ancestors and still no change.

Update: Ive tried getting rid of all CSS and also just trying to put a select tag with an option in the MainLayout file of Blazor and still no changes.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the value of `SelectClassName()`?

Comment: the class name can be nothing or "not-selected" depending on the binded value. This is just to highlight the field red if no input is selected. @AstridE.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the select element in the GUI to see what HTML has been produced? (Right-click + _Inspect_)

Comment: This definitely "feels" like a framework issue. Just to rule things out, what happens if you remove the outer `<ToolTip>` that surrounds the `<select>`? Also, it looks like you are dynamically assigning classes to your `<select>` and `<option>` elements so it's possible something in those classes is creating the separation. I just tried this locally using the styles you've given us here and there is no separation between the bottom of the select and the list of options.

Comment: I tried removing the <ToolTip> and nothing changed. I'll try to take a look at those classes. @Lex

Answer (score 1):

I just found out this is normal Microsoft Edge behavior. Running it on Chrome does not show the gap at all.

Comment: No surprise here - select and calendar inputs are both notoriously hard/impossible to style consistently which is on reason why there are so many plug0-ins generated for these that "hide" the basic ones and create some kind of replacement HTML to overlay it visually.